# how to get the child tag element from xml

Tags: xml

guys i have a xml file which is like this:

```
<Point  TestFlag="0" id="1" name="Conversation Set 1 Introduction"  practicenaturalfemale="practice_dummy.mp3" practiceusmale="practice_dummy.mp3">
        <PracticeText> </PracticeText>
        <PracticeFlag> 0 </PracticeFlag>
        <AudioFile gid="1" id="1" name="d002_p001.png" type="Img" />
        <AudioFile gid="1" id="2" name="d001_ae_p002_01.png" type="mp3" />
        </Point>
```

i need to fetch the the `d002_p001.png` which is in `<AudioFile>` tag and display it

how to do it please help

Comment: What is the programming language you are using??

Comment: i am using java as programming language

Comment: you have the answer below then. I've implemented the complete XML file parser using the below code. Try it for yourself :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using java, here is the code

Imports list

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
```

Initialisation part

```
String xmlFile = "audio.xml";

File xmlFileF = new File(xmlFile);

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
Document document = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(xmlFile);
```

Retrieve attribute name

```
Element audioFileElement = (Element)document.getElementsByTagName("AudioFile").item(0);
String fileName = moduleElement.getAttribute("name");
System.out.println(fileName);
```